# How to activate Javascript timezone support

Tags: javascript, jquery, timezone

I'm trying to have a page with various analog clocks of different timezones. 
I know I can do it manually with offset, but as I understand the support has all the data ready including the DST. I went through this 
[GitHub guide](https://github.com/mde/timezone-js)

So after I add the date.js file and link it to the website, as well the timezone data (olson/tzdata2018g.tar), there are two things I'm not sure about:

1. for making the files available I did this (in the jQuery file):

> ```
> timezoneJS.timezone.zoneFileBasePath = 'js/timezone-js/src';
>
> timezoneJS.timezone.init({ callback: cb });
> ```

And the callback gives me an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: timezoneJS is not defined

2. Then, let's say the data is availabe, is this date snipped enough to get a timezone?

> var dt = new timezoneJS.Date('10/31/2008', 'America/New_York');

Thanks

Comment: You should consider using Moment.js, check it out here: https://momentjs.com/

Comment: Please review your options [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15171030/634824).  If you still want to use timezone-js library, then please let us know.  Thanks.